# Factor score cannot be estimated

Tags: factor-analysis

I know this may turn out to be a software question, but since I get the same results in R and SPSS, I'm more interested in the conceptual side of what may be going on. I am running factor analysis on a dataset. KMO is fine (.89) and there are no issues with either sphericity or the determinant. When I save the factor scores, I see that the software does not produce factor scores for each individual. Basically, all their factor scores are left blank. Both SPSS and R produce the exact same results, regardless of factor extraction method. There are no missing values in the dataset and no outliers. The questions are measured on different scales, some are Likert-type questions, while some are percentage values from 0 to 100, yet others are scored on a scale of 0 to 10.

Is there any situation, mathematically, when a factor score simply cannot be computed for a set of variables?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Give the data snippet and the syntax, so people couuld try and reproduce your results.

Comment: Problem solved. While trying to find a reproducible snippet, it turned out that the person coding the data added a value actually in the range of the data as a missing value indicator, and both softwares were treating about 20% of the data as missing as a result. For these cases, obviously, no factor scores were calculated.

Comment: If the question is solved and the problem was due to a mistake such as you described, consider maybe to delete the question. Since it turn out to off topic.